# zend 2: Unsucessfully attempting to specify alternate db in local.php via 'adapter' keys

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying to have a specific module connect to a different database. [I already asked][1] about how to do this and was provided with [this link][2].

Its not terribly complicated, but it looks like I'm doing something wrong as I'm seeing a ServiceNotCreatedException.

Here is what my config/autoload/local.php looks like:

```
    return array(
        'db' => array(
            //Override global.php 'dsn' to specify local port on dev box
            'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;host=localhost;port=3307',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'pass!',
            'adapters' => array(
                'testdb' => array(
                    'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=otherdb;host=testsrv',
                    'username' => 'root',
                    'password' => 'pass',
                )
            )
        ),
    );


Now here is what I have the module's Module.php:

public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Helpdesk\Model\TicketTable' => function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('TicketTableGateway');
                $table = new TicketTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'TicketTableGateway' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('testdb');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(
                    new Ticket());
                return new TableGateway('ticket', $dbAdapter, null,
                    $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

Here is the method in the controller:

```
namespace Helpdesk\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Helpdesk\Model\Ticket;

class HelpdeskController extends AbstractActionController {
    protected $ticketTable;

    public function indexAction() {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'tickets' => $this->getTicketTable()->fetchAll()
        ));
    }
```

I'm using the TableGateway the same way the [zend tutorial][3] does. 
I'm doing this:

```
$dbAdapter = $sm->get('testdb');
```

Instead of this:

```
$dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
```

Am I misunderstanding this works?

edit:
here is the stack trace:

```
An exception was raised while creating "Helpdesk\Model\TicketTable"; no instance returned

App\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
App\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
[internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
App\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
App\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
App\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
App\public\index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
{main}
```

Comment: The error relates to `Helpdesk\Model\TicketTable` which isn't in the Module.php code you posted - could you edit your question to include that? I also wouldn't mix and match syntax for the DB config, so add a separate entry to the adapters array and move your zf2tutorial into that.

Comment: Hmm, according to the article linked to, the guy recommends doing it that way to specify a primary\default that the normal Adapter class will pick up and have the secondary adapters under the 'adapters' key which must be explicitly referred to. I also found I had some name-spacing issues which confused the problem. Soon I will re-edit the post so it is clearer.

Comment: Yup sorry, you're quite right, I just re-read the article. So the way you have it is fine.

Comment: Did register the abstract factory correctly ? When ServiceLocator can not find any service directly, it tries to get an instance from abstract factories

Comment: Just updated the post with more info.

Comment: Is the service declaration correct ? ("Ticket\Model\TicketTable" declared vs "Helpdesk\Model\TicketTable" called in your stacktrace)

Comment: Yes the service declaration should be correct because this works fine if I have only one data source in local.php and retrieve the generic 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'. My module name is "Helpdesk", but my models are 'Ticket.php' and 'TicketTable.php'. --- Come to think of it HelpdeskController should really be called TicketController, I realize that was a poor naming choice.

Comment: It is not a poor naming choice, business logic and controller are different thing, you can call several model in one controller...By the way I try to understand why you try to call `Helpdesk\Model\TicketTable` service if you have declared `Ticket\Model\TicketTable` ...

Comment: Ah I'm very sorry that was a typo. I fixed that, but did not update that code I posted. The stack trace and the current error message are correct though- with the correct namespace I am getting the error\stack trace. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about you approach but i needed a secondary db in my project so this is what i did :

config :

```
'mail_db' => array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
    'database' => 'iptcms_mail',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
),
```

factory:

```
namespace Mail\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class DbAdapter implements FactoryInterface{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
        $adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['mail_db']);
        return $adapter;
    }
}
```

and factory config:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'mail_db_adapter' => 'Mail\Factory\DbAdapter',
    ),
),
```

if you cant figure out how to fix this you can do it like this.

Comment: Up voted. I'll probably resort to that, but I'd still like to know why it isn't working the "right" way. I might ask on the zend forum and update this if I figure it out.

Comment: I don't know if this method is the best, or going through multi adapter config + AbstractDbAdapterFactory. I think abstract factories implementation decrease readability, as service names are not clearly defined.